# How to have a function executed each time the WMD preview is refreshed?

Tags: hook, preview, wmd, wmd-editor

I need to have a function executed each time the preview is refreshed for a WMD control.

Is there some function I can use to insert a hook for preview refreshes?

Answer (score 2):

```
var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1);

editor1.hooks.set("onPreviewRefresh", HtmlUpdated);

editor1.run();
```

}

```
function HtmlUpdated(){
...deal with it...
}
```